# How to get table to overflow within a flex div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div which is an item within a flexbox. Inside of this div, I have a table that is wide and tall. I want to be able to scroll around within this div so that I can see the whole table (scrollable vertically and horizontally) when the browser is resized small enough to cut off the table.

I tried to set this div's overflow to auto, but it is not scrolling to the rightmost side of the table and I am unable to see the vertical scroll bar because of this.

Problem is demonstrated in this
JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zn84rLwa/

How can I scroll around and see the whole table within this div (#inner2bottom)?

HTML Code:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div>
    Hello This is a div.
  </div>
      <div id="inner1">
          <div id="inner2">
            <div id="inner2top">
                Inner 2 top.

            </div>
            <div id="inner2bottom">
                Inner 2 bottom.
                <table>
                table stuff...
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
}

#outer {
  display: flex; 
  height: 70vh; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  align-items: stretch;
  border-style: solid;
}
#inner1 {
  flex: 1;
  border-style: dotted;
}
#inner2 {
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: column; 
  height: 100%;
}
#inner2top {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: cyan;
}
#inner2bottom {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly pointer... in your HTML snippet above you are missing `> </div>` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#inner1#` div in your fiddle was unnecessary. You can remove it and add `overflow:auto` and the rules from `#inner1` to `#inner2`. You can also add `overflow:auto` to `#inner1` in your original example and it will work as well.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
}

#outer {
  display: flex; 
  height: 70vh; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  align-items: stretch;
  border-style: solid;
}

#inner2 {
  flex: 1;
  border-style: dotted;
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: column; 
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#inner2top {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: cyan;
}
#inner2bottom {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div>
    Hello This is a div.
  </div>
    <div id="inner2">
      <div id="inner2top">
                Inner 2 top.     
      </div>
      <div id="inner2bottom">
                Inner 2 bottom.
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>aoisdjfo;ajw;eoajw;eofjefi;awoefj</th>
                <th>oaisjdfoiajoifj</th>
                <th>foiajoijf</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to rename your `divs` because I was getting very confused, but after renaming them and establishing a clearer idea how everything was nested, I came up with the following:

```css
body {
display: flex;
}

.outer {
display: flex;
flex: 1 1 auto;
height: 70vh; 
border-style: solid;
}

.nested-level-1-left {
flex: 1 1 auto;
background-color: yellow;
}

.nested-level-1-right {
flex: 1 1 auto;
border-style: dotted;
}

.nested-level-2 {
display: flex; 
flex-flow: column;
height: 100%;
}

.nested-level-2-top {
flex: 1 1 auto;
background-color: cyan;
}

.nested-level-2-bottom {
flex: 1 1 auto;
overflow: auto;
}

th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="nested-level-1-left">
<p>Hello This is a div.</p>
</div>

<div class="nested-level-1-right">

<div class="nested-level-2">
<div class="nested-level-2-top">
<p>Nested Level 2 Top.</p>
</div>

<div class="nested-level-2-bottom">
<p>Nested Level 2 Bottom</p>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Start date</th>
<th>Salary</th>
<th>aoisdjfo;ajw;eoajw;eofjefi;awoefj</th>
<th>oaisjdfoiajoifj</th>
<th>foiajoijf</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Start date</th>
<th>Salary</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Tiger Nixon</td>
<td>System Architect</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>61</td>
<td>2011/04/25</td>
<td>$320,800</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Garrett Winters</td>
<td>Accountant</td>
<td>Tokyo</td>
<td>63</td>
<td>2011/07/25</td>
<td>$170,750</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ashton Cox</td>
<td>Junior Technical Author</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>66</td>
<td>2009/01/12</td>
<td>$86,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cedric Kelly</td>
<td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>2012/03/29</td>
<td>$433,060</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Airi Satou</td>
<td>Accountant</td>
<td>Tokyo</td>
<td>33</td>
<td>2008/11/28</td>
<td>$162,700</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Brielle Williamson</td>
<td>Integration Specialist</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>61</td>
<td>2012/12/02</td>
<td>$372,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Herrod Chandler</td>
<td>Sales Assistant</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>59</td>
<td>2012/08/06</td>
<td>$137,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rhona Davidson</td>
<td>Integration Specialist</td>
<td>Tokyo</td>
<td>55</td>
<td>2010/10/14</td>
<td>$327,900</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Colleen Hurst</td>
<td>Javascript Developer</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>39</td>
<td>2009/09/15</td>
<td>$205,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sonya Frost</td>
<td>Software Engineer</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>2008/12/13</td>
<td>$103,600</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jena Gaines</td>
<td>Office Manager</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>2008/12/19</td>
<td>$90,560</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Quinn Flynn</td>
<td>Support Lead</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>2013/03/03</td>
<td>$342,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Charde Marshall</td>
<td>Regional Director</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>36</td>
<td>2008/10/16</td>
<td>$470,600</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Haley Kennedy</td>
<td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>43</td>
<td>2012/12/18</td>
<td>$313,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
<td>Regional Director</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>2010/03/17</td>
<td>$385,750</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Michael Silva</td>
<td>Marketing Designer</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>66</td>
<td>2012/11/27</td>
<td>$198,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Paul Byrd</td>
<td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>64</td>
<td>2010/06/09</td>
<td>$725,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gloria Little</td>
<td>Systems Administrator</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>59</td>
<td>2009/04/10</td>
<td>$237,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bradley Greer</td>
<td>Software Engineer</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>41</td>
<td>2012/10/13</td>
<td>$132,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Dai Rios</td>
<td>Personnel Lead</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>35</td>
<td>2012/09/26</td>
<td>$217,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
<td>Development Lead</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>2011/09/03</td>
<td>$345,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Yuri Berry</td>
<td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>40</td>
<td>2009/06/25</td>
<td>$675,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Caesar Vance</td>
<td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>2011/12/12</td>
<td>$106,450</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Doris Wilder</td>
<td>Sales Assistant</td>
<td>Sidney</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>2010/09/20</td>
<td>$85,600</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Angelica Ramos</td>
<td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>47</td>
<td>2009/10/09</td>
<td>$1,200,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gavin Joyce</td>
<td>Developer</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>42</td>
<td>2010/12/22</td>
<td>$92,575</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jennifer Chang</td>
<td>Regional Director</td>
<td>Singapore</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>2010/11/14</td>
<td>$357,650</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Brenden Wagner</td>
<td>Software Engineer</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>2011/06/07</td>
<td>$206,850</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fiona Green</td>
<td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>48</td>
<td>2010/03/11</td>
<td>$850,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shou Itou</td>
<td>Regional Marketing</td>
<td>Tokyo</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>2011/08/14</td>
<td>$163,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Michelle House</td>
<td>Integration Specialist</td>
<td>Sidney</td>
<td>37</td>
<td>2011/06/02</td>
<td>$95,400</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Suki Burks</td>
<td>Developer</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>53</td>
<td>2009/10/22</td>
<td>$114,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
<td>Technical Author</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>2011/05/07</td>
<td>$145,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gavin Cortez</td>
<td>Team Leader</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>2008/10/26</td>
<td>$235,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Martena Mccray</td>
<td>Post-Sales support</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>46</td>
<td>2011/03/09</td>
<td>$324,050</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Unity Butler</td>
<td>Marketing Designer</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>47</td>
<td>2009/12/09</td>
<td>$85,675</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Howard Hatfield</td>
<td>Office Manager</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>51</td>
<td>2008/12/16</td>
<td>$164,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hope Fuentes</td>
<td>Secretary</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>41</td>
<td>2010/02/12</td>
<td>$109,850</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vivian Harrell</td>
<td>Financial Controller</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>62</td>
<td>2009/02/14</td>
<td>$452,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Timothy Mooney</td>
<td>Office Manager</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>37</td>
<td>2008/12/11</td>
<td>$136,200</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
<td>Director</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>65</td>
<td>2008/09/26</td>
<td>$645,750</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Olivia Liang</td>
<td>Support Engineer</td>
<td>Singapore</td>
<td>64</td>
<td>2011/02/03</td>
<td>$234,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bruno Nash</td>
<td>Software Engineer</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>38</td>
<td>2011/05/03</td>
<td>$163,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
<td>Support Engineer</td>
<td>Tokyo</td>
<td>37</td>
<td>2009/08/19</td>
<td>$139,575</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Thor Walton</td>
<td>Developer</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>61</td>
<td>2013/08/11</td>
<td>$98,540</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Finn Camacho</td>
<td>Support Engineer</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>47</td>
<td>2009/07/07</td>
<td>$87,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Serge Baldwin</td>
<td>Data Coordinator</td>
<td>Singapore</td>
<td>64</td>
<td>2012/04/09</td>
<td>$138,575</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zenaida Frank</td>
<td>Software Engineer</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>63</td>
<td>2010/01/04</td>
<td>$125,250</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zorita Serrano</td>
<td>Software Engineer</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>56</td>
<td>2012/06/01</td>
<td>$115,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
<td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>43</td>
<td>2013/02/01</td>
<td>$75,650</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cara Stevens</td>
<td>Sales Assistant</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>46</td>
<td>2011/12/06</td>
<td>$145,600</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hermione Butler</td>
<td>Regional Director</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>47</td>
<td>2011/03/21</td>
<td>$356,250</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lael Greer</td>
<td>Systems Administrator</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>2009/02/27</td>
<td>$103,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jonas Alexander</td>
<td>Developer</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>2010/07/14</td>
<td>$86,500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shad Decker</td>
<td>Regional Director</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>51</td>
<td>2008/11/13</td>
<td>$183,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Michael Bruce</td>
<td>Javascript Developer</td>
<td>Singapore</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>2011/06/27</td>
<td>$183,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Donna Snider</td>
<td>Customer Support</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>2011/01/25</td>
<td>$112,000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div> <!-- End of Nested Level 2 Bottom -->
</div> <!-- End of Nested Level 2 -->
</div> <!-- End of Nested Level 1 Right -->
</div> <!-- End of Outer -->
```

Comment: When the browser is compressed horizontally to the point where the columns on the right of the table are cutoff, the scroll bar does not allow me to see all the columns still.

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: Chrome. JustH's solution worked for me though. I'm not sure it was browser dependent. But nevertheless, thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Ah, very good, not to worry - JustH's approach is much better than mine! It never occurred to me to simply remove `.nested-level-1-right` to make things easier :-)